# Find the sum of all even-valued terms in the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm having trouble figuring why the following code isn't producing the expected output. Instead, result = 272 which does not seem right.

```
/*
 *Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
 *Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million.
 */

public class Fibonacci 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=2;i<=33;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("i:" + fib(i)); 
            if(i % 2 == 0) //if i is even 
            {
                result += i;
                System.out.println("result:" + result); 
            }
        }
    }   
    public static long fib(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
            return n;
        else
            return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `result += i;` doesn't add a *Fibonacci* number to `result`.

You should be able to figure out how to make it add a *Fibonacci* number to `result`.

*Hint*: Consider making a variable that stores the number you're trying to work with.

Comment: Also, the line `if(i % 2 == 0)` doesn't test whether a *Fibonacci* number is even.

Comment: @rampion: Yes; that too.  (I thought he actually wanted even _inidicies_)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you got one thing wrong for the Fib. The definition for Fib can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.

Second of all (i % 2) is true for every other number (2, 4, 6 and so), which will man that it is true for fib(2), fib(4), and so on.

And last, result += i adds the index. What you wan't to add is the result of the fib(i). So first you need to calculate fib(i), store that in a variable, and check if THAT is an even or odd number, and if it is, then add the variable to the result.

**[Edit]**
One last point: doing fib in recursion when you wan't to add up all the numbers can be really bad. If you are working with to high numbers you might even end up with StackOverflowException, so it is always a good idea to try and figure a way so that you don't have to calculate the same numbers over and over again. In this example, you want to sum the numbers, so instead of first trying fib(0), then fib(1) and so on, you should just go with the list, check every number on the way and then add it to the result if it matches your criteria.

Comment: its actually an exercise on project euler, and i was able to figure it out. thanks though

Comment: @SLaks Good point. Tried to edit, but I'm affraid it's too late :-P

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a good starting point, but it's C, not Java. Still, it might help: [link text](http://blog.hazardousgaming.info/59/c---fibonacci-sum-of-terms-in-a-sequence/)